# Amazon MWS api library getreportsample php file returning string

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I tried running the API using the samples I've set the configuration and It's returning the product information but the problem is It's in string format this is the code that's returning the data as string stream_get_contents

```
echo (stream_get_contents($request->getReport()) . "\n");
```

I want to play with the data that MWS is returning like the price, quantity, ASIN etc

Answer (score 0):

the data being returned by $request->getReport() is resource type so I need to manage the data using fgetscv